# how to average in a specific dimension with numpy.mean?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix called POS which has form (10,132) and I need to average those first 10 elements in such a way that my averaged matrix has the form of (1,132)

I have tried doing

`means = pos.mean (axis = 1)`
or
`menas = np.mean(pos)`

but the result in the first case is a matrix of (10,) and in the second it is a simple number

i expect the ouput a matrix of shape (1,132)

Comment: Try `axis=0` instead of 1.

Comment: thanks, i tried it but the result is (132,)

Comment: As @thesilkworm said, use `axis=0`.  The shape of the result will b `(132,)`.  To have the shape be `(1, 132)`, add the argument `keepdims=True`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, now it's working

Comment: @Adam.Er8, there was nothing wrong with your answer--just add the `keepdims=True` to complete it.  (If I sometimes give what turn out to be answers in the comments, that's my problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to specify the correct axis and use `keepdims=True` which is noted by several commenters (If you add your answer I will delete mine).

This can be done with either `pos.mean(axis = 0,keepdims=True)` or `np.mean(pos,axis=0,keepdims=True)`